# Spark Structured Streaming: Running Kafka consumer on separate worker thread

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

So I have a Spark application that needs to read two streams from two kafka clusters (Kafka A and B) using structured streaming, and do some joins and filtering on the two streams. So is it possible to have a Spark job that reads stream from A, and also run a thread (Called `consumer`) on each worker that reads Kafka B and put data into a map. So later when we are filtering we can do something like `stream.filter(row => consumer.idNotInMap(row.id))`?

I have some questions regarding this approach:

1. If this approach works, will it cause any problems when the application is run on a cluster?
2. Will all `consumer` instance on each worker receive the same data in cluster mode? Or can we even let each `consumer` only listen on the Kafka partition for that worker node (which is probably controlled by Spark)?
3. How will the `consumer` instance gets serialized and passed to workers? 
   Currently they are initialized on Driver node but are there some ways to initialize it once for each worker node?

I feel like in my case I should use stream joining instead. I've already tried that and it didn't work, that's why I am taking this approach. It didn't work because stream from Kafka A is append only and stream B needs to have a state that can be updated, which makes it update only. Then joining streams of append and update mode is not supported in Spark.

Here are some pseudo-code:

```scala
// SparkJob.scala
val consumer = Consumer()
val getMetadata = udf(id => consumer.get(id))
val enrichedDataSet = stream.withColumn("metadata", getMetadata(stream("id"))
```

```java
// Consumer.java
class Consumer implements Serializable {
  private final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> metadata;

  public MetadataConsumer() {
    metadata = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    // read stream
    listen();
  }

  // process kafka data inside this loop 
  private void listen() {
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
      KafkaConsumer consumer = ...;
      while (consumer.hasNext()) {
        var message = consumer.next();
        // update metadata or put in new metadata
        metadata.put(message.id, message);
      }
    });
    t.start();
  }

  public String get(Integer key) {
    return metadata.get(key);
  }
}
```